# html image Expires headers (y-slow recommendation)

Tags: html, http-headers, yslow

The Y-Slow plug in for FireFox suggested I add long term expires headers to my img and script tags.

How is that done in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't (and can't be) done in HTML. It is done with HTTP. Almost always by [configuring your web server](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#IMP-SERVER). How you do that depends on which webserver you use.